# Multi-line function call not indented correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, phpcodesniffer

In the coding standards that I'm using we use 2 spaces for indentation

```
<!-- Tabs should represent 2 spaces. -->
<arg name="tab-width" value="2"/>

<!-- Set the default indent value and force spaces instead of tabs -->
<rule ref="WordPress">
    <exclude name="Generic.WhiteSpace.DisallowSpaceIndent" />
</rule>
<rule ref="Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent">
  <properties>
    <property name="indent" value="2"/>
    <property name="tabIndent" value="false"/>
  </properties>
</rule>
<rule ref="Generic.WhiteSpace.DisallowTabIndent" />
```

Which is generally working fine, but if I have, for example this

```
<?php

class MyClass{
  public function my_function() {
    add_submenu_page(
      'my-top-level-slug',
      'My Custom Page',
      'My Custom Page',
      'manage_options',
      'my-top-level-slug'
    );
  }
}
```

Where the arguments of the `add_submenu_page()` functions are I am getting

> Multi-line function call not indented correctly; expected 8 spaces but found 6

So the 'correct' would look like

```
<?php

class MyClass{
  public function my_function() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'my-top-level-slug',
        'My Custom Page',
        'My Custom Page',
        'manage_options',
        'my-top-level-slug'
    );
  }
}
```

But that's 2 spaces too much. I found some issues on github, but didn't find a solution for this.

How to fix this?

Comment: Please read this [https://github.com/DennisBecker/php-code-formatter] how to format of PHP code on GitHub

Comment: This has nothing to do with php_code_formatter, but with WordPress Coding Standards and PHP_CodeSniffer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, PHPCS doesn't yet have shared config settings, so you need to set the indent settings for the other sniffs that are reporting errors as well.

If you add the `-s` command line argument to PHPCS, you'll get a sniff code for each error message. That code tells you which sniff reported the error and needs changing.

In this case, I think it is the `PEAR.Functions.FunctionCallSignature` sniff.

The settings for this sniff can be found here: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Customisable-Sniff-Properties#pearfunctionsfunctioncallsignature

If that's the one, you'll need to add this to your ruleset:

```
<rule ref="PEAR.Functions.FunctionCallSignature">
  <properties>
    <property name="indent" value="2"/>
  </properties>
</rule
```

Comment: That seems to be the one. So basically if I see that happening in other places I need to see which sniff is causing it, and then change the property? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yes, that's the process you'll need to go through. Glad it worked for you.